# Trying to add shading to selected Bootstrap 3 Navbar

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a Navbar with Bootstrap 3. My questions is how to have it be shaded when selected?
Everything works fine otherwise. I believe it required some JavaScript, but I don't know how to implement it.

This is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div style="font-family:Webdings;">
      <%= link_to "lalala", root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><%= link_to "laaa", lal_path %></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">lala<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "lala", laa_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "lalala", lala_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "lalala", lala_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="https:lalala" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @lalala</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="lalala" data-width="600" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
      </li>
      <li><%= link_to "lala", contact_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "lalalala", register_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 is all you need! Go here: http://css3generator.com/. After you generate the shadow, gradient or text shadow you like, apply that css3 chunk of code to the element by adding :active selector. See here for :active selector: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

**NB:** :active MUST come after :hover (if present) in the CSS definition in order to be effective!